# Names.Add in VBA using variables

Tags: excel, vba, variables, named-ranges, contiguous

How can I create the following non-contiguous named range using the following variables?

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Validation_Range", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "='Holding Template'!R3C1,'Holding Template'!R4C2"
```

Here are the variables:

```
Dim PM As Range
Dim statement_date As Range

Set PM = ws.Range("A3")
Set statement_date = ws.Range("B4")
```

If I use 1 variable it works but I am unable to use more than one variable to create the non-contiguous range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how you are getting the two ranges to set your variables to but here are some shorthand options using the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx).

```
Dim pm As Range, statement_date As Range
With Worksheets("Holding Template")
    Union(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(4, 2)).Name = "Validation_Range"
    'alternate
    'Union(.Range("A3"), .Range("B4")).Name = "Validation_Range"
    'alternate
    'Set pm = .Range("A3")
    'Set statement_date = .Range("B4")
    'Union(pm, statement_date).Name = "Validation_Range"
End With
```

Any of these methods creates a named range of workbook scope or overwrites the *RefersTo:* of an existing *Validation_Range* named range with workbook scope.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. The Union function seems to make it easy to combine the variables in one place. Thanks!

Comment: This portion of the code is exactly what I needed. Thanks again! 'Union(pm, statement_date).Name = "Validation_Range"

Answer (score 0):

Create a name like you want manually and then see how it is put together. Then write code to assemble such a string.

Something like this seems to work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim PM As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim statement_date As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Holding Template")
    Set PM = ws.Range("A3")
    Set statement_date = ws.Range("B4")

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Validation_Range", RefersTo:= _
        "='" & ws.Name & "'!" & PM.Address & ",'" & ws.Name & "'!" & statement_date.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I renamed all the headings in my spreadsheet:

```
Sub renameheader()
i = 5
For x = 1 To 30
Worksheets("CHECKALL_LIST").Cells(1, i).Name = "Checks_" & x
i = i + 3
Next
End Sub
```

The headings were merged every 3 cells, which is why I needed to use the "i".  Hope this helps.